Windows Authentication using service account in .NET 8 console application and gMSA in Task Scheduler
EDIT: as @Panagiotis Kanavos wrote - this probably a question about the use of group managed service accounts. This is where I will try to find the reason for the error.
--- original entry ---
I'm trying to use a service account to authenticate a .NET 8 console application (output type set to "Windows Application") with a SQL Server. (The application is run by "Task Scheduler".)
I have been looking into using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate but as I am using IHost for dependency injection, I am not able to use "UseAuthentication()" which is used in all the example that I have found.
I have not been able to find any documentation or guides that show how this should/can be done - in a console application. I have found several guides that shows how to use Windows Authentication with ASP.NET application.
Question:
Can someone point me in the right direction as how to use Windows Authentication with a console application (WinExe)?

What do you mean use a service account to authenticate? A scheduled job runs under the account you specified in Task Scheduler. That can easily be (and usually is) a service account. No extra code is needed in the application itself. UseAuthentication() is used in Web apps, to authenticate client requests to the web app

The problem is that when I use the service account to authenticate the application (through Task Scheduler) the application is not able to access the database. I have not been able to locate any problems concerning the service account login-configuration/rights on the Sql Server  so I  was "hoping" that the problem was in my application. (Have been rewriten.)

The application doesn't get authenticated. It's executed under by an already authenticated account, the one you specified in Task Scheduler. If the application tries to connect to SQL Server using Window Authentication, it will actually try to connect using the task's execution account. That Windows account must exist as a login in the database and have permissions to connect. If you try to use a local account to connect to a remote server though, the local account won't be recognized. The connection will be done using the machine's computer account.

If you want the application to connect to a database using Windows authentication you'll have to run it using an account that has permission to connect to the database.

This might be the problem. Normally I use a "normal" service account but in this case I have been provided with at group managed service account. Is this something that I should investigate?

I think you should edit the question and add the relevant information there. This doesn't seem to be about programming at all though. The real question is how to use a gMSA in Task Scheduler. Check Using Group Managed Services Account with Scheduled Tasks. At the very least the gMSA must have the Logon as Batch privilege locally. Try with a simple script like the one used in the article to ensure the gMSA has the correct privileges and run the script before you try with your own application.

You are probably right. I will "follow that road". Thank you for your time.
